# Get the first word from fgets

Tags: c

I am using `strncpy(justLine, buf, charsToWrite)` to pass input into `char input[255]`. Now I would like to get the first word from this.

I managed something like this:

```
int spaceIndex = strchr(input, ' ');
char firstWord[spaceIndex];
strncpy(firstWord, input, spaceIndex-1);
firstWord[spaceIndex] = '\0';
```

Unfortunelly this is not working properly. Do you have any ideas?

I also tried using `strtok` but it is messing up with `input`.

Comment: return type of `strchr` is `char*`, not `int`.

Comment: What do you mean by _not working properly_?

Comment: Use `strcspn` like this : `size_t len = strcspn(input, " ");
char firstWord[len + 1];
strncpy(firstWord, input, len);
firstWord[len] = '\0';`

Comment: Out of curiosity: *how* and *why* are you "using strncpy ..." in the not-mentioned code before this short snippet? Are you aware of the possible problems caused by using `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`?

Answer (score -1):

You need to allocate a *string* with size `spaceIndex+1.`
Your code is almost correct, you are just not remembering that the `'\0'` terminator is part of the *string* when you allocate it and when you call `strncpy`.

You need two fixes:

1. Add one more `char` to `firstWord`:

   `char firstWord[spaceIndex + 1];`
2. Be aware of that extra byte on the call to `strncpy`:

   `strncpy(firstWord, input, spaceIndex+1);`

   I recommend actually using the buffer size as paramenter:

   `strncpy(firstWord, input, sizeof(firstWord));`

Read [`strncpy`'s documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy), although you are using it correctly, this function is really tricky.